# How to use the retrieveConnected method?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to know how to use the `retrieveConnected()` method from the `Bluetooth` `class` please. This class is part of the CN1Bluetooth.cn1lib.

I don't know how to get the paired devices with this method.

Unfortunately, there are no examples about the using of this method.

EDIT:
I used retrieveConnected() as you told me to do:

```
Button retco = new Button("Retrieve");
    this.add(retco);
    retco.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                debug("Action performed 1: "+ev);
                debug("Bt: "+bt);
                ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
                //ar.add("180D");
                debug("array: "+ar);
                bt.retrieveConnected(
                        new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                                debug("actionPerformed : " + ev);
                                main.add(new SpanLabel("TEST 3"));
                                debug("ev.getSource() = " + ev.getSource());
                                JSONObject res = (JSONObject)ev.getSource();
                                debug("RES = " + res);
                                try {
                                    updateUI(res);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    debug(e.getMessage());
                                }
                            };
                        },ar);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                debug(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

private void updateUI(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
    this.add(new SpanLabel(obj.toString()));
    this.add(new SpanLabel("TEST"));
    this.revalidate();
}
```

But i have those error messages

```
ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of []
at ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:448)
at ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
at ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:253)
atcom.codename1.cordova.CordovaCallbackManager.sendResult(CordovaCallbackManager.java:50)
at com.codename1.cordova.CallbackContext.sendPluginResult(CallbackContext.java:26)
at com.codename1.bluetoothle.BluetoothLePlugin.retrieveConnectedAction(BluetoothLePlugin.java:1212)
at com.codename1.bluetoothle.BluetoothLePlugin.execute(BluetoothLePlugin.java:306)
at com.codename1.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:34)
at com.codename1.cordova.CordovaNativeImpl.execute(CordovaNativeImpl.java:14)
at com.codename1.cordova.CordovaNativeStub.execute(CordovaNativeStub.java:9)
at com.codename1.cordova.Cordova.execute(Cordova.java:29)
at com.codename1.bluetoothle.Bluetooth.retrieveConnected(Bluetooth.java:129)
at be.ssii.app.forms.EidReader$3.actionPerformed(Unknown Source:97)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:570)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:604)
at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:708)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3369)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4552)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2180)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1152)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1070)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

There is one device paired to the device which use the app but it doesn't detect the paired one. It should work, the paired device is a BLE device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method retrieved paired Bluetooth LE devices. In iOS, devices that are "paired" to will not return during a normal scan. Callback is "instant" compared to a scan. UUID filtering might not work on Android, so it returns all paired BLE devices.

```
bluetoothle.retrieveConnected(e -> { }, params);
```

The `params` value is an array of service IDs to filter the retrieval by. If no service IDs are specified, no devices will be returned.

E.g.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.add("180D");
a.add("180F");
```

On success you should get an array of device objects as a result.

However looking at the code here: https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone/blob/master/CN1Bluethooth/src/com/codename1/bluetoothle/Bluetooth.java#L135

It looks like this line is wrong and should be changed from this:

```
plugin.execute("retrieveConnected", j.toString(), callack);
```

To this:

```
plugin.execute("retrieveConnected", callack, callack, j.toString());
```

But I haven't tested this.